# Using Liquid, is there a way to filter an array and ignore non matching items

Tags: arrays, filter, liquid

Using Liquid for a store.

I want to look through an array of values and check to see if any of those values match another list of values. If they match i want to display them. if they do not match i want to ignore them.

I'm currently able to do it in reverse by looking at all the values then 'remove' the ones i don't want individually but that is a terrible way to do this.

```
{% for 'field' in [metafield.key.value] | split: ", " %}
  {% if field == 'value 1' or field == 'value 2' or field == 'value 3'%}
    <div>
     field
    </div>
  {% else %}
    {% continue %}
  {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

for future weary travelers:

this works you may need to adjust where you're splitting the string:

```
{% assign metafield_str = product.metafields.yada.yada | split: "," %}
{% assign control_str = 'value, something, test, test2' | split: "," %}

{%- capture variable -%}
{% for c_str in control_str %}
  {% for m_str in metafield_str %}
    {% if c_str == m_str %}
      {{m_str}}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
{%- endcapture -%}
```